# Does Duelist's Crippling Critical counts for the max number of crit feats used in a turn?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

Imagine a character which would become a Duelist 10, focused on doing crits with his weapon. So, he would go all the way until he gets Stunning Critical. The question is:

Could the character accumulate the Stunning Critical feat power with the class ability Crippling Critical or would he need Critical Mastery for doing both? Does the class ability counts as a critical feat for this stacking purpose?

Comment: Just a thought that hit me, though, the *effects* may not stack. Bleed, for instance, is not stackable, so using the Cripling Critical bleed with the Bleeding Critical only apply the highest of the two. Be mindful of interactions between your critical effects.

Comment: Yes, true. You couldn't sum up the bleed from both sources. Just Bleeding Critical stacks with itself as it is stated in the feat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Both capacities stack

The Crippling Critical ability states that:

> When you confirm a critical hit using a light or one-handed piercing weapong, you can apply one of the following penalties [...list of possible penalties...] 
>   These penalties last for 1 minute, except for the ability damage, which must be healed normally, and bleed damage, which continues until the target receives magic healing or a DC 15 Heal skill check.

The Critical feat special caveat states:

> You can only apply the effects of one **critical feat** to a given critical hit unless you possess Critical Mastery.

(Emphasis mine)

The restriction is aimed at critical feats. Crippling Critical is a class feature, and nothing in it states it counts as a critical feat regarding the critical feat caveat. Therefore, nothing stops you from using both on the same critical.

Possessing Critical Mastery would allow you the base "critical feat + Crippling Critical class feature" combo and add an extra critical feat to the mix.